# SQL Table Edit: Add DateTime value in table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I made SQL table editor for add info in some columns. But one column is set to "DateTime" in and application can't write it . Here is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


try

{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + textBox4.Text + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + textBox1.Text + ";" + "User ID=" + textBox2.Text + ";" + "Password=" + textBox3.Text;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user_ban (char_id, status, ban_date, ban_hour, ban_end) VALUES (@char_id, @status, DateTime @ban_date, @ban_hour, @ban_end)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@char_id", "1");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "1");          
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ban_date", "1");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ban_hour", "1");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ban_end", "1");              
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Char Banned");
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
}
```

Column 'ban_date' is set to DateTime.
Thank you!

Comment: If `ban_date` column is `DateTime`, why you want to insert `1` to it? Does not make sense. `1` is not a valid `DateTime`.

Comment: is your table columsn set to datetimes? i see you passing "1" as a date is this correct?

Comment: The second error is here: `...VALUES (...., DateTime @ban_date,....` Don't specify datatype in `VALUES`

Comment: I changed column to int that why I wrote "1" . For test.

Comment: @xeLinxel then fix the second error

Answer (score 4):

`"1"` is not a date.  Try passing a date to it

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ban_date", DateTime.Today);
```

And remove the `DateTime` from the command string

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user_ban 
                      (char_id, status, ban_date, ban_hour, ban_end) 
                      VALUES 
                      (@char_id, @status, @ban_date, @ban_hour, @ban_end)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ban_date` column is `DateTime`, why you want to insert `1` to it? Does not make sense. `1` is not a valid `DateTime` at all. Change it to a valid [`DateTime`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) value.

Second, you should not use value type in your `VALUES` part. Change it from

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user_ban (char_id, status, ban_date, ban_hour, ban_end)
                       VALUES (@char_id, @status, DateTime @ban_date, @ban_hour, @ban_end)";
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^//delete this
```

to

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user_ban (char_id, status, ban_date, ban_hour, ban_end)
                       VALUES (@char_id, @status, @ban_date, @ban_hour, @ban_end)";
```